# Change custom message from function

Tags: php, function

I added a code snippet that was posted on another site to add a custom box for customers to fill out.  Works great except that the order confirm page shows the raw data instead of something custom facing.

Site I used for info: https://woosuite.com/woocommerce/add-notes-to-product/

Right now the output is "extra_product_field: Custom message".

How can I edit this in the below code to display something like "Comment:"

```
// Display custom field on single product page
    function d_extra_product_field(){
        $value = isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) : '';
        printf( '<br><br><div><label>Who is this for?</label><br><textarea name="extra_product_field" value="%s"></textarea></div>', __( 'Enter your custom text' ), esc_attr( $value ) );
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'd_extra_product_field', 9 );

    // validate when add to cart
    function d_extra_field_validation($passed, $product_id, $qty){

        if( isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) && sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) == '' ){
            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( '%s cannot be added to the cart until you enter some text in the field below.' ), $product->get_title() ), 'error' );
            return false;
        }

        return $passed;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'd_extra_field_validation', 10, 3 );

     // add custom field data in to cart
    function d_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

        if( isset( $_POST['extra_product_field'] ) ) {
            $cart_item['extra_product_field'] = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['extra_product_field'] );
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'd_add_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );

    // load data from session
    function d_get_cart_data_f_session( $cart_item, $values ) {

        if ( isset( $values['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item['extra_product_field'] = $values['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session', 'd_get_cart_data_f_session', 20, 2 );


    //add meta to order
    function d_add_order_meta( $item_id, $values ) {

        if ( ! empty( $values['extra_product_field'] ) ) {
            woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, 'extra_product_field', $values['extra_product_field'] );           
        }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'd_add_order_meta', 10, 2 );

    // display data in cart
    function d_get_itemdata( $other_data, $cart_item ) {

        if ( isset( $cart_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){

            $other_data[] = array(
                'name' => __( 'Brothers Name(s)' ),
                'value' => sanitize_text_field( $cart_item['extra_product_field'] )
            );

        }

        return $other_data;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'd_get_itemdata', 10, 2 );


    // display custom field data in order view
    function d_dis_metadata_order( $cart_item, $order_item ){

        if( isset( $order_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['extra_product_field'] = $order_item['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_product', 'd_dis_metadata_order', 10, 2 );


    // add field data in email
    function d_order_email_data( $fields ) { 
        $fields['extra_product_field'] = __( 'Customer Information: ' );
        $fields = ltrim($fields,'extra_product_field');
        $fields = 'Notes: ' + $fields;
        return $fields; 
    } 
    add_filter('woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 'd_order_email_data');

    // again order
    function d_order_again_meta_data( $cart_item, $order_item, $order ){

        if( isset( $order_item['extra_product_field'] ) ){
            $cart_item_meta['extra_product_field'] = $order_item['extra_product_field'];
        }

        return $cart_item;

    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_again_cart_item_data', 'd_order_again_meta_data', 10, 3 );
```

I tried using the ltrim put that doesnt produce any output.

```
        $fields['extra_product_field'] = __( 'Customer Information: ' );
        $fields = ltrim($fields,'extra_product_field');
        $fields = 'Notes: ' + $fields;
        return $fields;
```

```
        $fields['extra_product_field'] = __( 'Customer Information: ' );
        $fields = ltrim($fields,'extra_product_field');
        $fields = 'Notes: ' + $fields;
        return $fields;
```

Comment: Have you tried to assign the value to `$cart_item['Comment']` instead of `$cart_item['extra_product_field']`?